# How to search text inside the pages of all open browser tabs

Tags: search, browser-tab

I have 20+ tabs open in my browser and I need to be able to search for text **within** all the open pages.

When I google this, I find a bunch of advice on how to search for text in the browser tab names, but not how to search for content within the pages the tabs belong to. For example, it only searches for text in the `<title>Some title text here</title>` element of the HTML.

Currently I have to open each tab one by one, hit `ctrl+f`, enter my search term, then move onto the next tab if I don't find what I want. This is taking a long time. I want to be able to enter a search term and have the browser show me all tab pages that contain the text that matches my search term.

I'm using Edge (Version 120.0.2210.61), but if there's a way to do this in any other browser then I'll happily use that.